If I include my user ID in a domain redirect URL like arqade.com, will this still count toward the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges?
Several SE sites have alternate domain names that redirect to their main URLs.

Arqade redirects from arqade.com to gaming.stackexchange.com
Ask Different from askdifferent.com to apple.stackexchange.com
Cross Validated from crossvalidated.com to stats.stackexchange.com
Mi Yodeya from mi.yodeya.com to judaism.stackexchange.com
Seasoned Advice from seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com
Web Applications SE from nothingtoinstall.com to webapps.stackexchange.com

Note: The same applies for the respective meta site URLs, e.g., meta.arqade.com redirects to gaming.meta.stackexchange.com.
I’m curious if these redirects count toward earning the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges. These badges are awarded when you share a link (with your user ID) to a post that is subsequently visited by 25, 300, or 1000 unique IP addresses, respectively.
If I share a link that includes my user ID but uses the redirected domain, will it still qualify for these badges? For example, does a link like https://arqade.com/q/116133/4797 hold the same weight for badge consideration as its main domain counterpart, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116133/4797?
Relevant Arqade Meta post: Make formatting not take up characters in comments/chat?

From my own quick and simple observation, the answer is yes, you should still earn the badges.
How did I check? By monitoring the requests sent to the server and response it sends back, or more accurate the response headers.
When going to https://arqade.com/q/116133/4797 we get the following status code from the server:

Along with the following Location response header:

So as we can see, the browser is being redirected to the gaming.stackexchange.com domain, and the user id is preserved in the URL, meaning the end result is the same as if following the actual share link.
